# Puting ExpandaleListViews under Tab fragments created using action bar?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am building an App (a directory)!

I have customized the code and example from this tutorial............ 
"http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/"

But the challenge is:

How to put Expandable list views within the Tab fragments:
that is:

- ExpanbableListView in Top-rated
- ExpanbableListView in Games
- ExpanbableListView in Movies.

I tried many waysto put code in these classes (Top-rated, or games, or movies)!!

But my TabsPagerAdapter Class always gets this error:

- Type mismatch: cannot convert from Top-rated to Fragment.
- Type mismatch: cannot convert from Games to Fragment.
- Type mismatch: cannot convert from Movies to Fragment.

NB: I am maintaining the names as those of the tutorial...but they are changed in my app.

Here is the example of code to put an expanded list activity in the Games Fragment.

```
     import com.example.uganda.R;
     import android.app.ExpandableListActivity;
     import android.content.Context;
     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.view.LayoutInflater;
     import android.view.View;
     import android.view.ViewGroup;
     import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
     import android.widget.TextView;
     public class Games extends ExpandableListActivity {

   private static final String arrGroupElements[] = { "Football", "Rugby", "Cricket"};

   /**
* strings for child elements
*/

private static final String arrChildElements[][] = {
{ "Premiership teams","Country teams", "2014 worldCup"},

{ "Europe competitions","African competitions"},

{ "International tests","Local tonerments"}
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.fragment_games);
setListAdapter(new ExpandableListAdapter(this));
}

public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
private Context myContext;
public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context) {
myContext = context;
}
@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
return null;
}
@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
return 0;
}
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
if (convertView == null) {
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) myContext
.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
convertView = inflater.inflate(
R.layout.games_subitem_layout, null);
}
TextView yourSelection = (TextView) convertView
.findViewById(R.id.articleContentTextView);
yourSelection
.setText(arrChildElements[groupPosition][childPosition]);
return convertView;
}
@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
return arrChildElements[groupPosition].length;
}
@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
return null;
}
@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
return arrGroupElements.length;
}
@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
return 0;
}
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
if (convertView == null) {
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) myContext
.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
convertView = inflater.inflate(
R.layout.games_item_layout, null);
}
TextView groupName = (TextView) convertView
.findViewById(R.id.articleHeaderTextView);
groupName.setText(arrGroupElements[groupPosition]);
return convertView;
}
@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
return false;
}
@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
return true;
}
}
```

}

(This is the code for TabsPageAdapter that develops the errors)

```
   import com.uganda.TopRated;
   import com.uganda.Games;
   import com.uganda.Movies;
   import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
   import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
   import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
```

public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

```
public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {

    switch (index) {
    case 0:
        // Top Rated activity
        return new Private();
    case 1:
        // Games activity
        return new Missionary();
    case 2:
        // Movies activity
        return new Government();
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // get item count - equal to number of tabs
    return 3;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use either `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment` or `import android.app.Fragment` in all places. Make sure not to mix these two.